# Can anyone show me good tutorial about how to make complex iReport reports and exporting them to browser?

Tags: netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working on **iReport** in **netbeans IDE** .

I want to make reports that can be exported in browser in any **pdf** or **excel** format .

Can Any one show me a good tutorial or solution ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apress-The Definitive Guide to iReport is a good book and i think is the only think i found when i started to make reports.
Also you can query the iReport forum  [IReport forum](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=6)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this Google knol article helpful](http://knol.google.com/k/nasir-qureshi/jasper-reports-working-with-beans-and/3az55pmbwf6s/3#). But I bought the "Jasper Reports Ultimate Guide" -- it is a PDF eBook and has a great deal of information. Then I just searched for discussions of specific topics. You'll find that using the free iReport program will help you to construct reports and test various possibilities.

I also found that the [Jasper Reports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) gave me a fairly good set of info, when combined with examples from other people. As far as I know you can export almost any Jasper report to any of the formats. You can test the exports within iReport.

Comment: I just found this nice tutorial on DocStoc:
http://www.docstoc.com/docs/11752408/Jasper-Report-Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

- The ***[JasperReport Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)*** is very useful guide.
- [Here are](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html) a lot of samples how to design and build and different reports. Information provider by vendor.
- There are a lot of samples and solved cases on *SO*. IMHO, Out community helped thousands IT specialists to find solutions. You can use [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) tag to find information about *JasperReports*.
- *Jaspersoft* has its own [community](http://community.jaspersoft.com) that also contains a tons of useful information.